# Is it always 6 mundane attributes in D6?

Tags: d6-system

All books I've seen so far use exactly 6 attributes (sans any supernatural like force attributes, or magic attribute, ...) in D6.

So my question is: Is that only coincidence? Or is that like a core element (regardless of book or campaign) for the D6 system that there is always 6 attributes in D6?

Comment: Do you mean West End's D6 System and games built using it?

Comment: Yes exactly that

Answer (score 5):

No. But really Yes.

The game Ghostbusters was the first game to use a version of West End's D6 System, and it only used four attributes. If we include it in the D6 System, your answer is "no."

But that system had some significant differences besides the number of attributes. Traits were all whole numbers, no pips. And skills were not independently developed under each attribute. Instead, except for one "talent" you could assign for each Attribute, the Attribute score governed all uses related to the attribute.

If we limit to the games which share the more familiar refinements of the D6 System, with the pips and separately improvable skills, the answer appears to be "yes." I can find no official publication using more or less than six 'mundane' attributes.

Comment: 7? (is it not 6 + 1 supernat for those sry had been unspecific but didnt count the supernatural in my question?). so ghostbustrres uses less. are there any others without the supernatural that are not 6 (mundane) attributes?

Comment: The supernatural attribute is still defined as an attribute within the rules I quoted. Those rules say Seven attributes. Still in light of your revised question, I will revise, and still say no because Ghostbusters still only uses four.

Comment: tnx (if you hadnt mentioned also ghostbusters I would have not corrected the question to what I had in mind originally as it would have been unfair to your post, but as you had also mentioned them and they are still an example for also the corrected question I corrected it as your answer is still valid afterwards).

Comment: Had to change my answer. Ghostbusters was really more of a proto-D6 game. Star Wars was the first game using the refinements we'd come to know as D6.

Comment: kk tnx. From what I just heard the SRD (system core) shall mention the option to use different amounts of attributes. but interesting non the less that there is no game (aside from ghostbusters) that uses more/less than 6.